# How can GRPC server check the maxInboundMessageSize property set by grpc client

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

As a GRPC service owner, we need to log a message when the response we are trying to send is larger than the maxIncomingMessageSize set by the client.

This property is set by client to limit the size of the response they get.

Is there a way GRPC server gets a visibility on the value set by client on their side when a call is made from client to server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The server has no visibility of the client's maximum message size.

For a specific RPC method, you could add a request field where the client says the maximum they permit.

Generally it is best to not use such large messages and chunk instead. But when using the large messages is needed, the server could choose to dictate the maximum size it will generate (and the client has no choice but accept it) or have the client inform the server of its maximum.